# Websphere liberty - how to disable user credentials pop-up for basic registry credentials

Tags: authentication, websphere, websphere-liberty, openam, aaa-security-protocol

If We include `<feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>` in server.xml of websphere liberty, then user pop up comes to enter username/password.
How can we avoid that pop-up?
Note: We are using Open AM for authentication already & including appSecurity-2.0 as it helps us to retrieve the AM cookies/session information from AM.
So, just need a way to disable/avoid the local user pop-up?